# Google Contacts API - Regarding Deprecation of Contacts API and Remove API's

Tags: google-people-api

We have come across the update that Contacts API is getting deprecated but the old APIs are still working fine. Can you please let us know when will the old API's remove?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZFOQ.png)

Answer (score 1):

According the Google docs the Contacts API was shut down on January 19, 2022.
See here: https://developers.google.com/people/contacts-api-migration

Are you sure it's still working for you?
If so, I wouldn't count on it as it might break for you any day now.